# react-native: Custom Component pass component as property

Tags: react-native, react-native-text

I'm trying to extend the react-native `TextInput` (`RCTTextField`/`RCTTextFieldManager`) that I'm able to pass a react component (e.g. `<Picker >...</Picker>`) as an attribute (e.g. `input`) that will be set as the `UITextInput`s `inputView` attribute.

I'd expect to be able to pass a react component as a property to a native component as follows:

RCTTextFieldManager.m:

```
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(input, UIView)
```

Form.js

```
render() {
  return (
    <TextInput input={<Picker>...</Picker>} />
  )
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
2016-06-04 22:17:50.537 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue] Exception '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]' was thrown while invoking manageChildren on target RCTUIManager with params (
    9,
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
        (
        98
    ),
        (
        3
    ),
    "<null>"
)
```

(How) is it possible to pass a react component as a property to a native component?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I try to be able to set either a `Picker` or `DatePicker` as the `inputView` on the `UITextInput` so it displays a picker or date picker as the "keyboard". (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html)

Comment: i think closest property is `keyboardType` but im not sure it can do exactly what you need. Reference: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#props

Comment: React `TextInput`s `keyboardType` is iOS `UITextInputTraits` `keyboardType`. But I want to set `UITextField`s `inputView`. Since this is not (yet) supported I tried to extend the existing `RCTTextField` to allow for such a property but I don't know how to pass a react component as a property

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion. the better way is to customize your own UITextInput,and use a property like a inputType to decide what input view should be displayed.

Comment: That's what I thought about as a workaround. It would require loads of properties since configuring a picker or datepicker involves lot of configuration. Therefore I'd prefer the inputView option